# Loading multiple dted files using GDAL

Tags: gdal, dted

I have many files within different folders, for example:

```
/path/to/dted/e001/n40.dt1
/path/to/dted/e001/n41.dt1
/path/to/dted/e000/n40.dt1
/path/to/dted/e000/n41.dt1
```

I managed to load single `.dt1`-file (Python API):

```
gdal.Open('path/to/dted/e001/n40.dt1', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

Is there an option to load all the files as one dataset or merge many datasets into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both options are possible using GDAL via command line (or programmatically):

- you can load all the files as one dataset using [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html).

> This program builds a VRT (Virtual Dataset) that is a mosaic of the
>   list of input GDAL datasets. The list of input GDAL datasets can be
>   specified at the end of the command line, or put in a text file (one
>   filename per line) for very long lists, or it can be a MapServer
>   tileindex (see gdaltindex utility). In the later case, all entries in
>   the tile index will be added to the VRT.

Example: `gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list my_list.txt out.vrt`

- you can merge many datasets into one using [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html).

> This utility will automatically mosaic a set of images. All the images
>   must be in the same coordinate system and have a matching number of
>   bands, but they may be overlapping, and at different resolutions. In
>   areas of overlap, the last image will be copied over earlier ones.

Example: `gdal_merge.py -o out.tif --optfile my_list.txt`

or converting the above `out.vrt` to the desired format supported by GDAL (e.g. GTiff) using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).

> The gdal_translate utility can be used to convert raster data between
>   different formats, potentially performing some operations like
>   subsettings, resampling, and rescaling pixels in the process.

Example: `gdal_translate -of GTiff out.vrt out.tif`

Comment: Please note that DTED cannot be a target merge format, if you try to merge several dted using gdal_merge.py :  `Format driver DTED does not support creation and piecewise writing.
Please select a format that does, such as GTiff (the default) or HFA (Erdas Imagine).` VRT is a rather convenient method. Also, note that using `gdal_translate` with input [merged DTED in a VRT] to DTED format will result in a DTED 1degx1deg output (merging is then useless, since DTED driver is very strict)